# Simple example of how to define argument with argparse?

Tags: python

This must be super simple, but I'm struggling with the [official argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) - after 20 minutes of frustrated googling, I'm giving up and asking here!

I'm working in Python 2.7. I just want to run a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) with an argument, like this:

```
python manage.py my_command db_name='hello'
```

...and then from inside my script, get access to the value of `db_name`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    print args
    print options
```

This gives me

```
('db_name=mydb',)
{'pythonpath': None, 'verbosity': u'1', 'traceback': None, 'no_color': False, 'settings': None}
```

Is there an easy way (other than string-parsing `args` - surely that can't be the best way) to get the value of `db_name`?

Comment: Are you using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module? Also, how did `db_name` become `DB_NAME`?

Comment: argparse isn't designed to handle `name='value'` strings.  It deals with traditional Unix command line arguments like `--name value` (or just `value`).

Comment: Have you had a look at the content of `sys.argv`? If you only want to handle a few simple options, that's probably enough.

Comment: do you really need argparse? how many arguments do you have?  I second @jonrsharpe you really shouldnt be using argparse unless you have alot or very complicated arguments

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example for Django. That hadn't been included when I wrote my answer originally.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to make a slight modification to how you call your script, the below will work:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--db_name', action='store', dest='db_name',
                    help='Store database name')
results = parser.parse_args()
print "db_name:", results.db_name
```

You need to call it like this:

```
python script.py --db_name Test
```

Notice that you have to use traditional Unix command line arguments (`--name value`), instead of just `name=value`

The output of the above script is:

```
python script.py --db_name Test
db_name: Test
```

The `db_name` value is accessed with `results.db_name`

---

You can also access these arguments from custom Django Management commands. Utilizing the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#accepting-optional-arguments), I believe something like this will work:

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    # Named (optional) arguments
    parser.add_argument('--db_name',
        action='store',
        dest='db_name',
        help='Store database name')

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if options['db_name']:
        # do something with your db_name
```

In this case, your variable is accessed in `options['db_name']`

Comment: Did you mean to write the `=` sign on the line after "You need to call it like this:"?